# can religious symbols be patented

Tags: ca2558142a1

The symbols patented in this patent are actually religious symbols. They are not 'just' wellness symbols, but should be seen as symbols that open the door to divine healing energies, divine protection etc. Divine healing energies are always 'free' though, just like the air we breath (or even more so)! I see that the patent holder was not brazen enough to also include the crucifix symbol, as I doubt the patent would have gone through then?  Well, Reiki symbols are just as 'holy' to me (and I presume most Reiki practitioners and receivers) , as the crucifix is to a Christian - so I should be free to respectfully use such symbols (knit them on a scarf, or such for protection), as I please, and not fear legal prosecution for patent violation?
Regards,
Alexander Koop

Comment: I wonder whether a patent for a religious item could be refused as being contrary to the ordre public in countries where that is an exclusion. If you view religious practice as fundamental to society, then a patent which limits the practice of that religion would in principle be contrary to public order. I couldn't seem to find any actual law on this point though.

Answer (score 2):

This application was definitely too broad when it was filed, and it was abandoned.

If it had gone through, I would have recommended you post a [prior-art-request](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47/how-do-i-write-a-prior-art-request-for-a-u-s-patent-application/146#146) to our site. But you don't have to think about this now. It's like the application never happened, basically.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, very much appreciated. Sorry to be so ignorant, but is there anywhere on the patent, where I can see if a patent has been abandoned? Many thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderKoop No worries! It's not on the application itself, but it's listed a few places, the simplest of which being at the very bottom of [the Google Patents page](http://www.google.com/patents/ca2558142a1).